# Second packet read from input stream has incomplete data,

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I a simple server that receives bytes using TCP and then saves them to a file stream.   Through many tests I have seen that the first packet received is always just the filename with no other data. The second packet received only has one byte and it is the first letter of the input text file. After this all packets are sent correctly, but I can't seem to figure out what is messing up the second packet. It also appears that the last packet is written twice. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Here is an example Input/Output: https://www.diffchecker.com/srclclrx

```
    InputStream in = clntSock.getInputStream(); //server's input stream - gets data from the client
        OutputStream out = clntSock.getOutputStream(); //server's output stream - server sends data to the client

        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE];
        int count = in.read(byteBuffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
        String firstRead = new String(byteBuffer, 0, count);
        int fileNameEnd = firstRead.indexOf("\r\n");
        String fileName = firstRead.substring(0, fileNameEnd);

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName); //unzipped file output stream

        int contentBegin = fileNameEnd+2;
        byte[] oldBuffer = Arrays.copyOfRange(byteBuffer, contentBegin, count);
        int oldCount = count-contentBegin;
        String oldString = new String(byteBuffer, contentBegin, count-contentBegin, "US-ASCII");

        while((count = in.read(byteBuffer, 0, BUFSIZE)) != -1) { // read from origin's buffer into byteBuffer until origin is out of data
            String newString = new String(byteBuffer, 0, count, "US-ASCII");
            String combinedString = oldString + newString;
            int index = combinedString.indexOf("--------MagicStringCSE283Miami");
            if(index != -1){
                System.out.println("Final Print");

                byte[] combinedBuffer = concat(oldBuffer, byteBuffer);

                for(int i=0; i<index; i++){
                    System.out.print((char)combinedBuffer[i]);
                }
                System.out.println("");

                fout.write(combinedBuffer, 0, index);
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(+ oldCount);
            fout.write(oldBuffer, 0, oldCount); //write the byteBuffer's data to the client via the zip output stream
            fout.flush(); //push all data out of the zipOutputStream before continuing
            if(count == 1){
                for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
                    System.out.println((char)byteBuffer[i]);
                }
            }

            oldBuffer = byteBuffer;
            oldCount = count;
            oldString = newString;
        }
```

Edit: Another peculiarity to me is that the second to last packet is always just "-" and then the last packet has the remainder of the magic string which terminates the file output stream.

Comment: What EJP says.  For example, it's not guaranteed that 'firstRead' will contain a "\r\n".  If it has up to now, you've been lucky.

Comment: I know it isn't guarantee, but that part of the code works EVERY time. I am not even concerned about it. I will fix it when the more important problem is fixed. Every following read/write doesn't make any assumptions and the first  assumption is ALWAYS correct. Even if the 2nd read was only one byte the next read should have next contiguous data sent, but it doesn't and I can't imagine why that would be.

Comment: You should fix stuff that is known to be incorrect before it screws up you future debugging.  Also, 'The second packet received only has one byte and it is the first letter of the input text file' - OK what is wrong with that?  It's not a violation of the streaming protocol.

Comment: Below. Internet problem.

Comment: The problem is that the "P" is part of "Project Gutenberg". One would expect the next packet to at least contain "r", but instead it skips about the next 1000 words and picks up at another passage in the file. After this one skip no other characters are skipped in remaining iterations of the loop. I have checked that all of the data is being sent correctly.

Comment: TCP does not alter the content of the received data. You should consider to assist yourself in debugging to dump the content of what you receive before processing it further, byte per byte. You will see that nothing is missing and what you are doing wrong will surface. You should also read a bit more about the TCP protocol and try to build some understanding of what streaming really means. Because from what you are posting here it is clear that you don't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really sure that you are taking the full content of the data you receive ?

```
while((count = in.read(byteBuffer, 0, BUFSIZE)) != -1) { // read from origin's buffer into byteBuffer until origin is out of data
     add logic here to print count
     add logic here to print the content of the byteBuffer 
}
```

It is very likely that in your logic you are mistreating what you receive and somehow loose part of the data.
For instance your second packet where you claim to receive only '-' is the count then just equal to 1 ? It is possible that indeed this is the case with TCP, but you really have to verify that you are indeed processing everything that you receive. Based on your explanation I think you are dropping data, well not processing it correctly really.

Answer (score 0):

There are no messages in TCP and no guarantees about how much data each `read()` will return. It is only specified to transfer at least one byte in blocking mode, unless an error occurs.

One of the consequences of this is that it is impossible to write correct networking code without storing the result of `read()` in a variable, testing it, and then using it to delimit the amount of data processed.

Your expectations are at fault.

Comment: I used the integer returned from count every single time. Your answer literally has no relation to this question. The assumption isn't wrong because I have checked exactly what it read every time and it is ALWAYS reading the same amount at each read.

Comment: The answer is correct but you don't understand what streaming is. Because you keep insisting on the idea that there are packets in TCP, there are no packets in TCP. You must create your code as such that even if you receive the data byte per byte it would still work.

Comment: There are packets in TCP. https://systemstechblog.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/tcpheader.jpg I know that the code has to account for that and it does.

Comment: There are no packets in TCP. Packets are sent and received end to end. In TCP we receive segments. ref http://superuser.com/questions/298087/whats-the-difference-between-a-tcp-segment-and-a-tcp-packet. You just call each thing you receive a packet but that is not the correct terminology.